# Green's Theorem with logarithm

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, vector-analysis, greens-theorem

Question:

> Using Green's Theorem, show that for a region in the complex plane $D$, with $z_0$ not in $D$, $$\iint_D \frac{1}{z_0-z} \,dx\,dy = \oint_{\partial D} \log(z_0-z)\,dy.$$

First of all, I'm pretty sure the $dy$ is a typo on the right hand side, and should read "$dz$". In any event, I'm totally lost on how to do this. I know that I can write $\log(z_0-z)$ as $\log|z_0-z| + i\arg(z_0-z)$, but this doesn't help me use Green's Theorem, since we can't take any partial derivatives of the $\arg$ function.

I know that Green's Theorem is $$\iint_D (Q_x - P_y) \,dx\,dy = \oint_{\partial D} P\,dx+Q\,dy,$$ but I'm having trouble making my equality look like this one.

Comment: Since $z_0$ is not in $D$, the complex logarithm is analytic inside $D$.  And $\arg(z)$ is, therefore, also single-valued in $D$.  So, one can differentiate $\arg(z)$.

Comment: In expressions like $\displaystyle \iint (Q_x-P_y)\,dx\,dy,$ one normally puts a small space before each of $dx$ and $dy$ (although all sorts of clumsy uses are seen in postings here, including those that neglect that. I changed that in the question and also changed $\displaystyle \int\int_D$ to $\displaystyle\iint_D$ (coded as \iint_D) and fixed the strange position of the comma.